# UIPageControl with table views

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uipageviewcontroller

I haven't been able to find a solution to this yet, hoping for some clarification!

I want to be able to achieve a page view in my app with 2 or 3 views, but i want these views to be table views. Probably not table view controllers, but tables embedded in view controllers.

I've found some half-decent tutorials for page controllers, but nothing that touches on table views.

Think Twitter and thats sort of what I'm after!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your problem you need to follow these 4 steps:

1) create a UIViewController with Interface Builder

2) Inside this ViewController add a UIScrollView and a UIPageController

3) Inside the ScrollView you can put all the views you need (Tableviews in your case)...

4)As i see you want to put 3 tableviews...so add 3 tableviews.

After these Steps, you can easily with the following code customize the ScrollView and UIPageController:

in ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource,UIScrollViewDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UITableView *tableview1;
    IBOutlet UITableView *tableview2;
    IBOutlet UITableView *tableview1;



    IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem*SideBar;


    IBOutlet UIScrollView*scrool;
    IBOutlet UIPageControl*PageControl;
}

-(IBAction)ChangeView:(id)sender;

@end
```

Now that we already Config the Header we can pass to ViewController.m file where we gonna setup the UIScrollView, UIpagecontroller and the different tableviews:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

//Here we Config the PageControl that we declared in .h to do the function ChangeViews.

    [pageControl addTarget:self action:@selector(ChangeViews:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    [super viewDidLoad];


}
```

For ScrollViewDelegate :

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [scrool setScrollEnabled:YES];


    [scrool setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scrool.frame.size.width*3
                                ,scrool.frame.size.height)];



}


- (IBAction)ChangePage:(id)sender {
    CGFloat x = PageControl.currentPage * scrool.frame.size.width;
    [scrool setContentOffset:CGPointMake(x, 0) animated:YES];
}

-(void) scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView  {
    NSInteger pageNumber = roundf(scrool.contentOffset.x / (scrool.frame.size.width));
    PageControl.currentPage = pageNumber;
}
```

After These Steps You need to config the different Tableviews...I recommend you to Set different Tags to the three tableviews (es: tableview1.tag = 1....etc) then in the different phases of the tableview Setup announce this:

**EXAMPLE:**

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

int x;

if(tableview.tag ==1){

 x= 10;

}else if(tableview.tag == 2){

x= 3;
}else if(tableview.tag ==3){

x = 4
}

return x;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: When you say add 2 tableViews, how should they added in the scrollview o storyboard? next to each other, on top of each other?